# What does "Charge Shot!!!" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[This](http://www.charge-shot.com/) is the blog. Does it mean a shot that has been charged (i.e. the power for which has been accumulated), or is it some kind of a reference? I have no idea.

Comment: It's only a name, the important stuff is inside the blog. I can name a blog "crazy-bananas", and you would come to ask: "why is it named crazy-bananas?" I think it is off-topic.

Comment: Yeah, but I understand "more or less" what "crazy-bananas" are. The bananas which are crazy. And in this case I don't. If people say that you can't tell what "Charge Shot!!!" means it also will be an answer for me.

Comment: I think it's a reference to charge shots in video games. (Maybe not any *particular* video game…?)  I haven't heard of this blog, but it looks like they started out as a blog about video games and expanded to other topics later.

Comment: @user3724662 The question "is this an allusion to a English figure of speech I don't recognize" is a legitimate question for this forum, regardless of where the phrase is found. P.S. in your made up example, it would be pertinent to point out that "bananas" is a slang idiom for "crazy", and as such "crazy-bananas" may not refer to mentally unwell fruit, but to extreme zaniness.

Comment: @snailboat - I noticed the two co-editors (and several of the staff) attended school in [Ohio](http://www.charge-shot.com/p/about-writers.html), and one of them is a self-described "avid baseball fan". I wonder if it's mere coincidence that the name of the blog rhymes with a former (controversial) [team owner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marge_Schott) from that same area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **charge shot** is a gaming maneuver whereby a character or weapon builds up power and then emits the accumulated charge in one or more shots or strikes.

Here's a description of a charge shot in Super Smash Bros. Brawl: [charge shot](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Charge_Shot)